# Advance Search in Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Thanks for guide, This question is done and I corrected my code and after edit and update my question I found out that it create confusions so I created another question Thanks for your help

I have a problem for searching data, I got this error message yesterday

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WomenNew.Models.News_]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'WomenNew.Models.News_'.

but today I correct my code and now the situation of view and other code is

My View is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AdvanceSearch_";
}
<h2>AdvanceSearch_</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("HtmlTextBox", "this is value")
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="text2">
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="text2">
    <input type="text" name="text3" value="text3">
    <input type="text" name="text4" value="text4">
    <input type="text" name="text5" value="text5">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

And my  action  is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdvanceSearch_(string Deatails, string text2, string text3, string text4, string text5, string HtmlTextBox)
{
    if ((text2 != null || Deatails != null || text3 != null || text4 != null || text5 != null))
    {
        ViewBag.txtDeatails = Deatails;
        ViewBag.test2 = text2;
        ViewBag.test3 = text3;
        ViewBag.test5 = text4;
        ViewBag.test4 = text5;
        ViewBag.HtmlTextBox = HtmlTextBox;
        return RedirectToAction("Index",db.News_.Where(x =>x.Deatails.Contains(txtDeatails)).ToList());

    }
    else
        return View("AdvanceSearch_");
}
```

Yesterday I got the error I mentioned in top of this question, but now search doesn't work  and in the list (Index view) all records are shown, I don't know how should i pass the query or this result of search to my list view (index) I use this code in index view and for one field search is successful but I need to search in another view for more than 10 columns  so I create another view named AdvanceSearch_ but I could not create search in another view  I mean  outside of view Index (my output view) . It took me more than one day and I really appreciate if anyone help me. I'm new in mvc

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You passing `List<News_>` to a view which has `@model News_`

Answer (score 0):

In your action, the result of `db.News_.Where(x => x.Deatails.Contains(Deatails)).ToList()` you are returning to your view, is a `List<WomenNew.Models.News_>` object.

In your view you stated that it the `model` is of type `WomenNew.Models.News_`.

Depending on what you actually want, you either change `@model WomenNew.Models.News_` to `@model IEnumerable<WomenNew.Models.News_>` or you return just one object, for instance: `return View(db.News_.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Deatails.Contains(Deatails)));` which will return the first object it finds in the database or a `Default(Deatails)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I made some mistake in my question let me correct the question and update to current situation and if you can pl. guide me,  I really appreciate you  Tomas.